# Using mod_rewrite and mod_alias (redirect 301) together in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, mod-alias

I have a site with a set of old .html and .php pages that have been put into a CMS.

Currently in the .htaccess file there are about 30 mod_alias redirects in the following form:

```
redirect 301 /oldpage1.html http://www.example.com/newpage1.php
redirect 301 /oldpage2.php http://www.example.com/newpage2.php
redirect 301 /oldpage3.php http://www.example.com/newpage3.php
```

But we want to use mod_rewrite to have pretty URLs in our CMS, which will take the form `http://www.example.com/pagename.php`, so also have the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1
```

At the moment both are being applied together, which results in:

```
http://www.example.com/newpage1.php?page=oldpage1.html
```

How can I apply the rewrite rule only when no match has been made by the mod_alias redirect 301 statements, so that the following occurs:

`http://www.example.com/oldpage1.html` -> redirects to ->
`http://www.example.com/newpage1.php` -> which is treated as ->
`http://www.example.com/index.php?page=/newpage1.php`

Any hints would be very much appreciated? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the answer in a [great explanation of mod_rewrite and mod_alias](http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=358)

The problem is that mod_rewrite always occurs before mod_alias, regardless of the order the are placed in .htaccess. This is the reverse of the order required for this situation.

The trick is to use `RewriteRule [R=301]` instead of `redirect 301`, and hence use mod_rewrite for everything instead of mixing it with mod_alias.

Full solution is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^oldpage1.html /newpage1.php [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^oldpage2.php /newpage2.php [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^oldpage3.php /newpage3.php [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1
```