# Redirect to new url using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to do a url redirect but the way I have the .htaccess file it doesn't seem to work. Is there a specific place or format I need to use for the redirect?

Below is my .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Redirect 301 /research/report-listings/ http://example.com/research/research-portfolio/

# END WordPress

# BEGIN wtwp_cache
# END wtwp_cache

# BEGIN wtwp_security
# END wtwp_security
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't want to mix mod_alias directives with mod_rewrite directives. Both modules will end up getting applied to the same request and you can end up with some wonky redirects. Best to just use mod_rewrite if you've rules for things like Wordpress.

Note: the order is very important

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^research/report-listings/(.*)$ http://example.com/research/research-portfolio/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: I was about to add to my answer that he should [just use mod_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808014/mod-rewrite-or-mod-alias) since he already has it.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your `Redirect` directive inside of a `<IfModule mod_alias.c>...</IfModule>` block. Then, make sure you have `mod_alias.c` installed and enabled:

```
apache2ctl -M  #This is for Linux systems
```

Comment: I tried that and it still doesn't seem to work. When I go to the page it doesn't follow the redirect it just gives me a 404

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856193/using-mod-rewrite-and-mod-alias-redirect-301-together-in-htaccess) the same problem you're having.